# Application crashed after splash screen when testing with Testlfight

Tags: ios, swift, testing, crash, testflight

I've just deployed my application on TestFlight for internal test.
When I install my app on my iPhone and launch it, it crashed on the splash screen. But when I deploy my application on my phone with xcode, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I use Xcode. After the launch screen, i display a login windows. It just initialize some UIImage (like background) and create my tables in my DB SQLite :/

FIXED ! One of my library wasnt loaded ! for fixed that, i added this library in "embedded binaries" in the general setting of my app :)

Comment: are you connected to wifi on both?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin, Xcode, Phonegap?

Comment: This may be for a lot of reasons, memory warnings is just one of them. Please state more details about your app.

Comment: are you using storyboard or nib file? if you are using the old school nib file, then you might need to recheck the project compiled source to see whether the xib file is added into the list.

Comment: Yes, both were connect to wifi, and i code on xcode.
I use storyboard + some .xib file for make my popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it ! Thank you all for yours responses. That was a library loading problem.

I edited my original post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try archive ipa from XCode and install it via iTunes, is it crashed?

I meet the same problem when I test it work correct in my phone but Apple Reviewer say it crashed when start up app.

My problem: When start app, I have a processing data so long in main thread, it's freeze app about 10s, app will be killed.

Comment: My app crashed after 1 or 2 second only :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149960/iphone-app-crashes-only-in-release-mode-on-3g
Do you try this? "Optimization Level" set None for release mode. Sometimes I met this issue

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the target deployment iOS version is compatible with the user's iOS version.

Sometimes users on testflight don't update iOS, or iOS releases an update that the user installs immediately and the build actually isn't compatible.

I had this particular experience with Crashlytics and iOS 8.1 -> 8.2

Comment: I launched the app on my phone with testflight too, and it crashed. :/ My iOS version is the last and support my app.